# How to use JsonPath expression with wildcards in MS SQL 2019's Json_Value?

Tags: sql-server, wildcard, jsonpath

In my SQL Table, I have a column storing JSON with a structure similar to the following:

```
{
    "type": "Common",
    "items": [
        {
            "name": "landline",
            "number": "0123-4567-8888"
        },
        {
            "name": "home",
            "number": "0123-4567-8910"
        },
        {
            "name": "mobile",
            "number": "0123-4567-9910"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the table structure I am using:

```
CREATE TABLE StoreDp(
[JsonData] [nvarchar](max), 
[Type] AS (json_value([JsonData],'lax $.type')) PERSISTED, 
[Items]  AS (json_value([JsonData],N'lax $.items[*].name')) PERSISTED
)
```

Now, when I am trying to insert the sample JSON (serialized) in the table column [JsonData], I am getting an error

> JSON path is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '*' is found at position 3.

I was expecting data to be inserted with value in [Items] as "[landline, home, mobile]"

I have validated the jsonpath expression, and it works fine except for in SQL Server.

Update: Corrected the SQL server version.

Comment: *"in MS SQL 2018"* There is no SQL Server 2018; the latest version is 2019 and the version prior to that was 2017.

Comment: `json_value` cannot do this kind of shredding and rebuilding. You could do it with `OPENJSON` and `STRING_AGG`, but not in a computed column, only a regular query. Perhaps a scalar UDF, although that can have major performance impacts.

Comment: @Larnu Sorry about the typo. Corrected the version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server cannot do shred and rebuild JSON using wildcard paths and `JSON_VALUE`.

You would have to use a combination of `OPENJSON` and `STRING_AGG`, and also `STRING_ESCAPE` if you want the result to be valid JSON.

```sql
SELECT
  (
    SELECT '[' + STRING_AGG('"' + STRING_ESCAPE(j.name, 'json') + '"', ',') + ']'
    FROM OPENJSON(sd.JsonData, '$.items')
      WITH (
        name varchar(20)
      ) j
  )
FROM StoreDp sd;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f47dcaf1e246bdb16facfeac886598b3)

You could only do this in a computed column by using a scalar UDF. However those have major performance implications and should generally be avoided. I suggest you just make a view instead.